# How to write math notation in legend?

Tags: r

I need to write mathematical notation in the legend of my box plot in R. but I don't know how to write it.

Here is my code :

```
boxplot(postive[,7],negative[,7], col=c("red", "green"), names=c("Positive Coefficient","Negative Coefficient"), main="",cex.axis=1.5,cex.lab=1.5,ylab="Rank" ,outline=FALSE)
legend(0.80,95000, box.col="white",cex=1.5, c("MWW P-value = 1.4 * 10^-16"))
```

basically, I want to write `1.4 * 10^-16` to appear like normal mathematics notation in literature, but I couldn’t figured out how to do it. can someone help me with this ?

Comment: `?plotmath` will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

You can use expression.

```
boxplot(postive[,7],negative[,7], col=c("red", "green"), names=c("Positive Coefficient","Negative Coefficient"), main="",cex.axis=1.5,cex.lab=1.5,ylab="Rank" ,outline=FALSE)
legend(0.80,95000, box.col="white",cex=1.5, c(expression(paste("MWW P-value = 1.4 * ", 10^-16))))
```